# React: Best way to setState on a large state properties

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm using `setState` to update text every time a user types, and so I want an efficient way of setting state.
I have a component with a state that looks something like this:

```
this.state = {
   property1:
    subpropertyA: {
      A1: {something},
      A2: {something},
      A3: {something},
      ...
    },
    subpropertyB: {
      B1: {something},
      B2: {something},
      B3: {something},
      ...
    },
  property2:
    subpropertyC: {...}
    ...
  }
```

What is the most efficient way of changing just one sub-sub property, eg A1 or A2? There are really 3 options:

#### This is what I've been doing, and it works fine:

```
let newState = this.state
newState.property1.subproperty2.A2 = (something)
this.setState({property1})
```

#### This is probably better practice, but is stupidly inefficient, creating a new object every time:

```
let newState = (a recursive clone of this.state)
newState.property1.subproperty2.A2 = (something)
this.setState({property1})
```

#### This doesn't work -- it leads to unpredictable results since (something) generates unique IDs. I have no idea why it breaks beyond that.

```
this.setState((state) => { 
  state.property1.subproperty2.A2 = (something)
  return {property1} 
})
```

Any ideas which of the above 3 is best? Can I keep using #1 in good conscience? And any idea why #3 breaks?

Comment: nah bro it literally says nothing about this

Answer (score 0):

```
let newState = this.state
newState.property1.subproperty2.A2 = (something)
this.setState({property1})
```

Whilst this might work, it's considered bad since you are not allowed to mutate `this.state` directly using `=` assignment.  Doing this will lead to very odd and hard-to-find bugs.

In this one, there appears to be no reference to `property1`. `state.property1` != `property1`.

```
this.setState((state) => { 
  state.property1.subproperty2.A2 = (something)
  return {property1} 
})
```

Your state is quite deep and you are right about how updating it can be painful.If performance matters to you, you should consider using the popular  copy-on-write libs like https://immerjs.github.io/immer/example-setstate. Keep in mind, they do under the hood, create a copy of the original object (this is fundamental and unavoidable in React. But it does it in a targetted way.

In React, creating new objects with values from the previous is pretty much a requirement. It's not that expensive because defining a new object is really quite cheap on the scale of things.

Though it would be quicker than `clone` to do this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => { 
  return {
      ...prevState,
      property1: {
         ...prevState.property1,
         subpropertyA: {
            ...prevState.property1.subpropertyA,
            A2:  (something)
         }
      }

  }
})
```